# Andengine spite animation giving wrong framecount exception

Tags: android, andengine, sprite

i am trying to animate a sprite with two frames...
animation works from frame 0 to 1 but gives "pFrameDurations does not equal pFrameCount!" exception while animating from frame 1 to 0.

```
sprite.setCurrentTileIndex(1);
sprite.animate(new long[]{200,0}, 1, 0, 0, new AnimatedSprite.IAnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStarted(AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite,
                                           int pInitialLoopCount) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationLoopFinished(AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite,
                                                int pRemainingLoopCount, int pInitialLoopCount) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationFrameChanged(AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite,
                                                int pOldFrameIndex, int pNewFrameIndex) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationFinished(AnimatedSprite pAnimatedSprite) {
            }
        });
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the signature of the method you are using:

```
public void animate(final long[] pFrameDurations, final int pFirstTileIndex, final int pLastTileIndex, final int pLoopCount, final IAnimationListener pAnimationListener);
```

You are setting first tile index as 1 and last tile index as 0.

If this is not a mistake and you want to animate backwards, you have to use the following method and specify the frames in desired order:

```
public void animate(final long[] pFrameDurations, final int[] pFrames, final IAnimationListener pAnimationListener);
```